# Can someone help me to understand this simple C++ operation function inside a function

Tags: c++

I'm new to programming and learning C++. I know the basics of C++, but I find this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int program(int a, int b) {
    if (a > b) 
    {
        return 0;   
    }
    else 
    {
        return a + program(a*2+1, b);   
    }
}

int main() {
  cout << program(1,2018);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2036
```

I know if the return is only `a`, the obvious answer is 1. I'm confused about is a calculation from `program(a*2+1, b)` and why the answer is 2036?

Comment: Please provide your code as text, not as a picture.

Comment: Just added the code (text).

Comment: What happened when you tried to trace through the logic of the program yourself? For example, what do you expect to be the result of `a*2 + 1`? What happens when you try using that result to call `program`? What happens when you add that result to `a`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does recursion work in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493347/how-does-recursion-work-in-c)

Comment: What's your best guess as to what that expression should do?

Answer (score 0):

So let's go through a recursion:

1. We get `return 1 + program(3, 2018)`

But what does `program(3, 2018)` return?

It returns `3 + program(7, 2018)`!

But we have to substitute the result of `program(3, 2018)` back into `return 1 + program(3, 2018)`

So we get `return 1 + 3 + program(7, 2018)`

This adds up `return 1 + 3 + 7 + 15 + 31 + ... + program(2047, 2018)`

`program(2047, 2018)` returns 0 since 2047 > 2018

Therefore `cout << 2036`

Comment: Ok so 2047 > 2018, ok i get it but how can it be 2036? cause the last loop is 1023

Answer (score 0):

It is recursive function, with every call it does (a*2 +1) till this expression is less than b.
So the callstack will look like

```
program(1   , 2018)
program(3   , 2018)
program(7   , 2018)
program(15  , 2018)
program(31  , 2018)
program(63  , 2018)
program(127 , 2018)
program(255 , 2018)
program(511 , 2018)
program(1023, 2018)
```

so your result will be sum of first parameter, which is equal to 2036

Comment: Thanks for your help it really means a lot

Comment: If you find it helpful, can you please upvote & accept my answere

Answer (score 0):

I'll start with a different easier question.

What is the output of

```
cout << program(9999,2018);
```

?

Well, you set `a` and `b` and look at the body of `program`:

```
if (9999 > 2018) 
{
    return 0;   
}
else 
{
    return 9999 + program(9999*2+1, 2018);
}
```

So

```
if (9999 > 2018)
```

this if branch is taken, it runs

```
{
    return 0;   
}
```

and the answer is it prints `0`.

Next, let us look at

```
cout << program(2000,2018);
```

again we substitute:

```
if (2000 > 2018) 
{
    return 0;   
}
else 
{
    return 2000 + program(2000*2+1, 2018);
}
```

now the first `if` branch condition is false -- `2000 > 2018` is false -- so we take the `else` branch.

```
    return 2000 + program(2000*2+1, 2018);
```

so what is `program(2000*2+1, 2018)`?  First, let's evaluate it.

```
 program(4001, 2018)
```

we don't know that, so we repeat the above analysis.  We use the *same technique* to solve for the value as we did for `9999` and `2000`.

```
if (4001 > 2018) 
{
    return 0;   
}
else 
{
    return 4001 + program(4001*2+1, 2018);
}
```

here

```
if (4001 > 2018)
```

the condition is `true`, so we take the first branch and

```
  return 0;
```

get 0.  So the value of `program(4001, 2018)` is `0`.

Going back:

```
    return 2000 + program(4001, 2018);
```

we substitute that back in

```
    return 2000 + 0;
```

and now we can solve it

```
    return 2000;
```

the value of `program(2000, 2018)` is `2000`.

Now, again, we try it for `program(1000, 2018)`.  It takes the second branch, and returns `1000 + program(2001, 2018)`, which becomes `1000+(2001+0)` after repeating the above work, which then evaluates to `3001`.  Feel free to try it yourself.

...

Back the the original problem, we look at `program(1,2018)`:

```
if (1 > 2018) 
{
    return 0;   
}
else 
{
    return 1 + program(1*2+1, 2018);
}
```

this takes the else branch, then does

```
    return 1 + program(3, 2018);
```

so we have to solve for `program(3, 2018)` next.

This is known as a recursive program.  When one of the values always grows/shrinks, and after a certain bound no longer does a 'recursive call', such programs are easy to show the recursion eventually halts.

Here we know this because `a` on each recursive call gets bigger, and when it passes `b` (which is never changed on each call) it stops recursing.  So if you just grind through each evaluation you'll eventually end up with a value that the entire thing returns.

Comment: Thanks for your help it really means a lot